# Число строк и столбцов в DATAGRID WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как из таблицы в DataGrid (WPF) получить число столбцов и строк? в формах было просто : `RowCount` и `ColumnCount` а как в wpf ?

Comment: В WPF вам не должно хотеться узнавать параметры ваших _данных_ и визуального элемента. Параметры ваших данных нужно смотреть у VM.

Comment: @VladD что такое VM? Недавно только слез с форм.

Comment: Ну это вам стоит почитать про MVVM. Если коротко, когда вы отделяете контент от представления, VM — это контент, а представление — это ваш XAML и его code-behind.

Comment: @VladD спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почти так же (напрямую):

```
int count_row = dataGrid.Items.Count; 
int count_col = dataGrid.Items[0].Cells.Count;
```

Через DataSource:

```
int count_row = ((DataTable)dataGrid.DataSource).Rows.Count; 
int count_col = ((DataTable)dataGrid.DataSource).Columns.Count;
```

Вот похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838679/row-and-column-count-of-data-grid-in-c-sharp